# Iterating over .xz files using lzma always ties the tar Header to the first line

Tags: python, compression, lzma

While iterating over .xz files using the code below, it seems like the tar header or something else I don't know of is tied to the first line of each file in the .xz.

Each .xz contains several .txt files that I want to get their data. Here's a small sample of the data: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1264134927500b143acf3aa05d61517520200504170531/47edc4

```py
import os, sys
import lzma

strPath = "./openwebtext"
fileList = os.listdir(strPath)
fileList = [os.path.join(strPath, item) for item in fileList]

for file in fileList:
    with lzma.open(file, "rt") as raw_data:
        for line in raw_data:
            print(line)
```

## Output

0478010-c220e751f9b4344cfb419c85e1f9cd34.txt0000644000000000000000000000144000000000000015112 0ustar  00000000000000A few challenge levels

0506072-909fa5f2b7a244ebacaa521125ebe7f2.txt0000644000000000000000000000222200000000000015306 0ustar  00000000000000Most top 10 lists of gaming are created with the express purpose of praising those titles that strive for excellence. Others are for making fun of those that don’t cut the mustard. This one is for actively ranting about games that are just far too offensive for their own good. Read on for ten videogames that are so racially offensive they should be avoided where possible. This list may contain material that some readers may find offensive.

0376076-ff4ad186cd4073d31f936f974d3b7b4d.txt0000644000000000000000000000604300000000000015217 0ustar  00000000000000Samuel E. Pope needed money fast. The landlord raised the rent on his Head to Toe hair salon in Southwest Washington, the bills were piling up, and he was on the verge of closing.

0537010-0d140b52bee6c724ec9e065e5f55a2b6.txt0000644000000000000000000000223700000000000015160 0ustar  00000000000000This week in the war, on 16 October 1941, Vichy head of state Maréchal Philippe Pétain pronounced prison sentences upon those he saw as responsible for the fall of France.

---

How can I get rid of these weird lines at the start of the strings?

I don't even succeed in removing them easily using `line = line[find(weird_text) + len(weird_text):]` (but I prefer a solution where this is not needed).

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data. Nobody want to download a `12Go` file for testing.

Comment: @AlexandreB. Thanks for the tip, just updated with a small sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I should have just used `tar -xf file` again as the files weren't .xz, they were .tar - although the different extension.